# What would be the partial derivative w.r.t to $a\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ of $(Xa)^TXa$?

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

What would be the partial derivative w.r.t to $a\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ of $$(Xa)^TXa$$

where $X\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$?

My attempt:

We know that $$\frac{\partial }{\partial a}(Xa)^TXa=\partial (Xa)^T(Xa)+(Xa)^T\partial (Xa)$$

We also know that $$\partial X^t=(\partial X)^T$$

So taking these facts into account:

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial a}(Xa)^TXa=X^TXa+a^TX^TX$$

Would this be correct?

I think it's equal to $2X^TXa$ but i'm not sure how to derive it.

Comment: [matrix cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf)? I think (78) on p.11 answers?

Comment: @BCLC I know it was there, but I was interested in solving this in particular. Thank you for pointing out though!

Comment: Slim Shady ah you mean you really wanted to understand the derivation and stuff for this particular case instead of just applying the formula (probably to understand how the general formula is obtained or something)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let's understand exactly what you are trying to do. You have a function $f \colon \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$ f(a) = \left( Xa \right)^T \cdot \left( Xa \right) = \left< Xa, Xa \right> $$
where
$$ a = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_n \end{bmatrix}. $$
Such a function doesn't have "a partial derivative with respect to $a$" but it has a differential, or a gradient, or has partial derivatives with respect to each of the variables $a_1,\dots,a_n$. I'll assume we are interested in computing the gradient of $f$. Note that your pruposed formula
$$ X^T X a + a^T X^T X $$
doesn't even compile as $X^T X a$ is a column vector while $a^T X^T X$ is a row vector so their addition is not defined.
The gradient of $f$ is given by
$$ \nabla f = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial f}{\partial a_1} \\ \vdots \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial a_n} \end{bmatrix}. $$
We have
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial a_i} = \left< \frac{\partial}{\partial a_i} (Xa), Xa \right> + \left< Xa, \frac{\partial}{\partial a_i} (Xa) \right> = 2 \left< \frac{\partial}{\partial a_i} (Xa), Xa \right> = 2 \left< X \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial a_i} a \right), Xa \right> = 2 \left< Xe_i, Xa \right> = 2 e_i^T X^T X a = \left< e_i, 2X^TXa \right> $$
which implies that $\nabla f = 2 X^T X a$ as required.

Comment: Re $$ X^T X a + a^T X^T X $$ and that it is row + column soooo why don't we think that OP just missed a transpose in exactly 1 of the terms in this case the 2nd term and so it's instead $$ X^T X a + (a^T X^T X)^T $$ as required? I mean, is it more than missing a transpose somewhere?

Comment: also levap, does the [matrix cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) help? I think (78) on p.11 answers the OP's question

Comment: @BCLC: No, basically the OP missed a transpose and one can use the techniques of the matrix cookbook to solve it "mechanically". However, from my experience, when beginners apply blindly the "matrix derivative rules", they arrive to all sort of absurd results (such as combining tensors of different types, getting a result which is "correct" up to a transpose and not understanding why, etc). Most of those mistakes can be eliminated by actually understanding what one is trying to compute and doing the computation explicitly.

Comment: 1 - ah so what OP did is something similar like applying the matrix cookbook or any formula really without really understanding the objects leading to nonsensical things like row + column and other stuff? 2 - but wait (78) on p.11 DOES answer the question right?